# fitting rectangle inside another rectangle in diagonal

Tags: geometry

Having the following case, where we want to fit a rectangle (c,d) inside another rectangle (a,b). We know that c>b or d>a so it will not fit horizontally, so we need to check if it will fit diagonally.
Example:
[image: square]
What would be the condition to check if the rectangle (c,d) will fit (a,b) or not.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: You say square, but do you really mean "rectangle"?

Comment: If both sides are larger, it will have a larger surface area, so how can you imbedd the larger rectangle into a smaller one?

Comment: Yes, I meant rectangle (updated)
Both sides are not bigger. Only one of them.

Answer (score 6):

Let $l=\sqrt{c^2+d^2}$ be the diagonal of the internal rectangle and $\phi=\sin^{-1}\frac{c}{l}=\sin^{-1}\frac{d}{l}$ the angle between the diagonal and a side.
Let $\alpha$ be the angle between $a$ and $c$.
Then the necessary and sufficient conditions for the internal rectangle to be inside the external one are
$$\begin{align}
a & \ge l\sin(\alpha+\phi) \\
b & \ge l\cos(\alpha-\phi)
\end{align}$$
Assume that $a<l$ and $b<l$ - otherwise the corresponding condition disappears and the problem is thus simplified.
The system of inequalities has a solution in $\alpha$ when 
$$ \sin^{-1}\frac{a}{l} - \phi \ge \cos^{-1}\frac{b}{l} + \phi $$
which is the condition you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Let $2a\geq2b$ and $2c\geq2d$ be the sidelengths of the two rectangles, and put $f:=\sqrt{c^2+d^2}$.

When $R_{cd}\subset R_{ab}$ can be realized then it can be done with common center $M$.

A necessary condition for such an inclusion is $d\leq b$, because otherwise $R_{cd}$ contains a disk of radius $d>b$, which cannot be covered by $R_{ab}$. If $c\leq a$ as well then $R_{cd}$ can be embedded in $R_{ab}$ with aligned sides.

Therefore it remains to consider the case $c>a\geq b\geq d$ which is shown in the following figure.

[image]

The short sides of $R_{cd}\subset R_{ab}$ are tangent to the circle (shown in blue) with radius $c>a$ and center $M$. This circle intersects $R_{ab}$ in four arcs cutting off the vertices of $R_{ab}$. It follows that the two shorter sides of $R_{cd}$ lie in two opposite corner regions of $R_{ab}$. Consider such a side. Its endpoints lie on a similar arc of a circle  with radius $f$ and center $M$. Therefore the  length $2d$ of this side is at most equal to the distance $|PQ|$ in the figure. This means that we have
$$(2d)^2\leq \left(b-\sqrt{f^2-a^2}\right)^2+\left(a-\sqrt{f^2-b^2}\right)^2\ .$$
Expressing $f$ in terms of $c$ and $d$, and simplifying, you obtain the condition you were looking for.