# Max width of rectangle inside another rectangle in diagonal

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, rectangles

> Given the hatch sizes (length $a$ and width $b$ of the external rectangle) and the length of the material (internal rectangle, $d$), what is the max width  $c$ of the material that can pass from the hatch?
>
> (The material is longer than the Hatch length ($d > a$) and less than the Hatch diagonal.)

A similar problem has been asked before
[fitting rectangle inside another rectangle in diagonal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/847282/fitting-rectangle-inside-another-rectangle-in-diagonal)
However, the answers are on equality or inequality on matching conditions.
As there is only one matching condition, is there any formula that gives the answer. (as $c=?$)

thanks

Nuvit

Note:The best solution that I could find is

c = d. (b.cos(t) - a.sin(t)) / (a.cos(t) - b.sin(t))

teta (t) as the angle between two rectangles. However still need to know angle teta.

an other formula showing the relation between a, b, d and angle teta:

(a+b)/(2d*(sin(t)+cos(t)) + (b-a)/(2d*(sin(t)-cos(t)) = 1

Comment: Looks like it's one of these answers. Not very pretty: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+for+c+in+(b+-+sqrt(c%5E2+%2B+d%5E2+-+a%5E2))%5E2+%2B+(a+-+sqrt(c%5E2+%2B+d%5E2+-+b%5E2))%5E2+-+(2d)%5E2%3D0

Comment: Did you find it?

Comment: The best solution that I could find is: